# Cannot read property something of null, mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

say I have this:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({
    amount: {
        monthly: { cost },
    },
}) => ({
    amount,
    period,
    interval,
})
```

it is complaining that it cannot read `cost` of null

this is because something monthly is null

is there a safeguard way that I can just return null for `cost` if monthly is null?

I have tried doing `cost: cost || null` or something but to no avail

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `monthly` is `undefined`. You can try with setting default value during the destructurization:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({
    amount: {
        monthly: { cost } = { cost: null },
    },
}) => ({
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I've changed the code to pass through as react props. so how would that look like this: `const { cost } = monthly`, how can I set cost here?

Answer (score 0):

In the reducers,you can define default value:

```
const initialState = {
  amount: {
        monthly: {},
    }
}
reducers = (state =initialState  )=>{
  ....
  return state;
}
```