# Check whether a nested prop is not undefined in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In case we need to get a deeply nested prop and the value could be undefined at every level. In other words, we need to check every level for whether the value is undefined. What would be a good practice to do so, or to avoid doing this at all?

A simple two-level example, imagine the depth to be five or six...

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        formValues: state.form.section1 ? 
                      state.form.section1.input1? 
                        state.form.section1.input1.value 
                        : {} 
                      : {}
    };
};
```

I found this post: [Cannot read property something of null, mapStateToProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51612012/cannot-read-property-something-of-null-mapstatetoprops), but I doubt if it's a good practice if the tree is tall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I handle this kind of situation like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    formValues: state.form && state.form.section1 && state.form.section1.input1 ? 
      state.form.section1.input1.value : {}
   };
};
```

You can avoid nested ternary operation which is not good practice.

Comment: Yeah sure, this is absolutely better than a ternary chain. Also looking for a way to avoid such check at all...in many open source projects, I don't see people check the props at all, not sure why.